# Adding a background process (celery) to a scaling app on OpenShift

Tags: scalability, openshift, haproxy

I am developing a scaling app for RH Openshift.
I plan to use three gears for the following purposes:
1) HAProxy and web cartridge
2) MySQL 5.1 database
3) Background process (Celery)

I have already setup the first two gears by creating a scalable app, and adding the MySQL database cartridge. How can I assign the last gear to run Celery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rhc cartridge-add https://raw.github.com/tresbailey/openshift-celery-cartridge/master/metadata/manifest.yml -a <appname>
```

I have not tested this cartridge, it's just one i found when searching for "openshift celery cartridge", but I can verify that it installs on it's own gear in a scaled application.  You can run `rhc app show <appname> --gears` to verify how many gears your application is using, and what cartridges each is running (both before and after installing the above cartridge)

Comment: I tested this, it installs on the main gear only. This means it wont scale. If anyone knows how to make a service  cartridge out of a python module please let us know.

Comment: Did you install it to a scaled application?  If not, then it will install to the only gear that is available.

Comment: Yeah I did and tried the command you suggested. I even forked it and tried to get it working as a service type cartridge on a scaled app but it couldn't access python. As as a plugin it could because it gets installed in the primary gear.